# How to annotate text in a constant vertical place of different geom_col plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I need to write a function that will make a `geom_plot` for different data, with different number of columns. I need to add a text annotation in a constant place of plot, no matter how many columns it will have. It will always be on `y = 1.02` and I want it to always be aligned to the right. My attempt on a single plot is below:

```
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(gear = as.factor(as.character(gear))) %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% summarise(qsec = sum(qsec)) %>% 
    mutate(qsec_index = qsec / mean(qsec)) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
        geom_col(aes(gear, qsec_index)) + 
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + 
        geom_text(aes(x = 3.4, y = 1.02, label = 'Average'))
```

[image]
But how can I automate it to be always aligned to the right, no matter if my underlying data have 2, 4, 5 etc. columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your annotation according to the number of levels of your x variable. Here we'll use `carb` instead of `gear` to demonstrate:

```r
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(carb = as.factor(as.character(carb))) %>% 
    group_by(carb) %>% summarise(qsec = sum(qsec)) %>% 
    mutate(qsec_index = qsec / mean(qsec)) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
        geom_col(aes(carb, qsec_index)) + 
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + 
        geom_text(aes(x = length(levels(carb)) + .4, y = 1.02, label = 'Average'),
                  hjust = 1, vjust = -1)
```

[image]

and it will still work as expected with `gear`:

```
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(gear = as.factor(as.character(gear))) %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% summarise(qsec = sum(qsec)) %>% 
    mutate(qsec_index = qsec / mean(qsec)) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
        geom_col(aes(gear, qsec_index)) + 
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + 
        geom_text(aes(x = length(levels(gear)) + .4, y = 1.02, label = 'Average'),
                  hjust = 1, vjust = -1)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What's the role of `hjust = 1` and `vjust = -1` if you already set the `x` and `y` position?

Comment: @Xaume these affect how the annotation is positioned as the image is scaled. If you know in advance the exact size of your image then these are unnecessary.